# NodeJS (EJS) adding stylesheet - not found

Tags: css, node.js, express, nginx, ejs

I try to add a CSS file in my node js project based on the EJS Template Engine, it does not work, the file cannot be found.

> GET http://localhost/css/bulma.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

**my project folder structure**

```
./index.js
./views
    /partials
        /header.ejs
./public
    /css
        /bulma.css
```

I have included app.use (express static) as follows

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

in my header.ejs I include the CSS file like this:

```
<link href="/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I've tried everything, it doesn't work.

This one doesn't work either:

```
app.use('public', function(req,res,next){
   console.log(req.url); // Never output
   next();
});
```

I have also tried the following:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

Does anyone here have any idea what the problem might be?

**EDIT**

**Full server code (index.js)**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// index page 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        template: '../pages/home'
    });
});

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

**index.ejs for dynamic template system**

```
<header>
    <%- include('../partials/header') -%>
</header>

<%- include(template) -%>

<footer>
    <%- include('../partials/footer') -%>
</footer>
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/nodejsproject/;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

and

```
console.log(__dirname + '/public');
```

is the **correct** path to the **node js project path**

**SOLUTION**:
The problem here was the NGINX config.

I have looked at the following:

https://geekflare.com/nginx-static-files-node-js/

I changed the config file like this:

```
upstream backend {
server localhost:3000;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name nodeproject;

root /home/nodeproject/;

location / {
try_files $uri @backend;
}

location @backend {
proxy_pass http://backend;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
# Following is necessary for Websocket support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
```

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` should work. Try logging `__dirname + '/public'` to make sure it has the correct value.

Comment: Can you post your full server code ? Perhaps some other middleware is preventing `express.static` to do its job

Comment: @Quentin Yes is the correct path to the node JS project.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your answer. I've edit the post above with the full server code

Comment: Can you post your NGINX config ?! OT: You HTML code from your page is invalid. Also why are you not serve the static files over NGINX ?

Comment: @Marc Why do you think nginx is used here? No need to (looks like a project for learning purpose).

Comment: @pzaenger When you visit his link, a 404 from NGINX is displayed, also server headers answer: `Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`, And: his code snippet listen on port 3000, but the page is on port 80 published

Comment: @Marc Ah, now I see :) My bad. OP should definitively add this information.

Comment: Hi @Marc Yes you're right I used NGINX. I simply forwarded the proxy_pass in the config file to http://localhost:3000; in file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default which also works. I have added my NGINGX config file above.

Comment: @DavDeveloper im not sure, but i assume the problem is the forward in nginx

Comment: @Marc Thank you very much! Its works now. I added above the solution, its was the NGINX config ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forward `/` but no sub directory/paths. Therefore nginx trys to find the `/css/bulma.css` in his `root /home/nodejsproject/` Try something like this:

```
location ~/(.*)$ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$1;
}
```

BUT: then your NGINX become nearly useless, because you forward **all** trafic to your node.js app

You should serve static files direct from nginx

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have already added a solution above that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I did the similar thing using class `hello` it works.

**my project folder structure**

```
./index.js
./views
    /partials
        /header.ejs
    /pages
        /index.ejs
        /home.ejs
./public
    /css
        /bulma.css
```

**bulma.css**

```
.hello {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**home.ejs**

```
<body>
  <h1 class="hello">Hello world!</h1>
</body>
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <header>
    <%- include('../partials/header') -%>
  </header>
  <%- include(template) -%>
</html>
```

**header.ejs**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
// set the view engine to ejs
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// index page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("pages/index", {
    template: "../pages/home"
  });
});

app.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("something bad happened", err);
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: So what are you saying? Is this a fix or are you saying his code works for you?

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` and `<link>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: I think the problem here is somehting else, the code snippet looks good, but his app runs behind a reverse proxy (nginx). i think the probleme is here, not the node app itself